# Spring Security using both username or email

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security in my Spring `MVC` app.

`JdbcUserDetailsManager` is initialized with the following query for authentication:

```
select username, password, enabled from user where username = ?
```

And authorities are being loaded here:

```
select u.username, a.authority from user u join authority a on u.userId = a.userId where username = ?
```

I would like to make it so that users can login with both username and email. Is there a way to modify these two queries to achieve that ? Or is there an even better solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunatelly there is no easy way doing this just by changing the queries. The problem is that spring security expects that the users-by-username-query and authorities-by-username-query have a single parameter (username) so if your query contain two parameters like

```
username = ? or email = ?
```

the query will fail.

What you can do, is to implement your own **UserDetailsService** that will perform the query (or queries) to search user by username or email and then use this implementation as authentication-provider in your spring security configuration like

```
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="xxx.yyy.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
  </beans:bean>
```

Comment: I've looked at the class but have a bit of trouble figuring out which methods should I overwrite. Any pointers?

Comment: I think I see it now: loadUserByUsername(String username)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and after trying with a lot of different queries, with procedures... I found that this works:

```
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    // Codificación del hash
    PasswordEncoder pe = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    String userByMailQuery = "SELECT mail, password, enabled FROM user_ WHERE mail = ?;";
    String userByUsernameQuery = "SELECT mail, password, enabled FROM user_ WHERE username=?";
    String roleByMailQuery = "SELECT mail, authority FROM role WHERE mail =?;";

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(pe)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(userByMailQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(roleByMailQuery);

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(pe)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(userByUsernameQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(roleByMailQuery);

}
```

Its just repeat the configuration with the two queries.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood this correctly, then the problem is that you want to lookup username entered by the user in two different DB columns.

Sure, you can do that by customizing UserDetailsService.

```
public class CustomJdbcDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl {

    @Override
    protected List<GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(String username) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(getAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(), new String[] {username, username}, new RowMapper<GrantedAuthority>() {
            public GrantedAuthority mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              .......
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(getUsersByUsernameQuery(), new String[] {username, username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
            public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                 .......
            }
        });
}
```

Your bean configuration for this class will look something like this.

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.xxx.CustomJdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value> YOUR_QUERY_HERE</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value> YOUR_QUERY_HERE</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Your queries will look something similar to this

```
select username, password, enabled from user where (username = ? or email = ?)
select u.username, a.authority from user u join authority a on u.userId = a.userId where (username = ? or email = ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your UserDetailesService.and config like the below code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

The point is that you don't need to return the user with the same username and you can get user-email and return user with the username. The code will be like the code below.

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        var user = /** here search user via jpa or jdbc by username or email **/;
        if(user == null ) 
            throw new UsernameNotFoundExeption();
        else return new UserDetail(user); // You can implement your user from UserDerail interface or create one;
    }

}
```

tip* UserDetail is an interface and you can create one or use Spring Default.

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom queries in `<jdbc-user-service>` tag in `users-by-username-query` and `authorities-by-username-query` attributes respectively.

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="" users-by-username-query="" authorities-by-username-query=""/>
```

**Update**

You can create class which implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` and configure your application to use it as an authentication source. Inside your custom UserDetails service you can execute queries that you need to obtain user from database.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing already and I've included both of them in my question. The issue is that I have to customize them to include both username and email.

Comment: You have not mentioned that you know how to configure them. And you are asking "Is there a way to modify these two queries to achieve that ?".

Answer (score 1):

You can config UserDetailesService class like this.

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userRepository.getUserByEmailOrUserName(username); //for fetch user
        if(user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exists");
        }
        UserDetailsImpl customUserDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(user);
        return customUserDetails;
    }

}
```

Your queries will look something similar to this

> select * from user where email = ? or username = ?

UserRepository class for fetch user data

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    @Query("from user where email = :u or username = :u")
    public User getUserByEmailOrUserName(@Param("u") String username);
    
}
```

You can also add phone number while doing login.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround I discovered.  Basically I'm concatenating username and email address with a delimiter character in between (for example 'jsmith~johnsmith@gmail.com'), and checking to see if the parameter matches the left side of the delimiter or if matches the right side of the delimiter:

```
select username, password, enabled 
  from users 
 where ? in (substring_index(concat(username, '~',email),'~', 1), 
             substring_index(concat(username, '~',email),'~', -1))
```

If you are concerned that the delimiter character (such as ~) might exist within the username or email, use a non-standard delimiter character instead (for example, X'9C')

Answer (score 0):

you can change your config as follows :

```
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return input -> repository.findByUsername(input)
                .orElseGet(() -> repository.findByEmail(input)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("account not found")));
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).